# Difficulty copying a single string in two substrings

Tags: c, string

I want to input a string and then make 2 substrings, first half in `first` string and second half in `second` string and if the string is odd then leave the middle element.

For input given as `tushar`, the output I am get is `tus` and an empty line.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        char str[1000];
        int i, j;
        while ((getchar())!= '\n');
        scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
        int len = strlen(str);
        char first[(len / 2) + 1];
        char second[(len / 2) + 1];
        for (i = 0; i < (len / 2); i++) {
            first[i] = str[i];
            second[i] = str[(strlen(str)) - i];
        }
        printf("%s\n", first);
        printf("%s\n", second);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, when and where are you null-terminating the new strings? Secondly, have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement to see what happens?

Comment: One problem is here: `second[i] = str[(strlen(str)) - i];` You may try `second[i] = str[((strlen(str))+1)/2 + i];`. And don't forget to add `\0` at the end of the strings.

Comment: @Damien but can you tell me what is the problem

Comment: With your code, `second[0] == '\0'`. It corresponds to `str[length(.)]`.

Comment: When `i == 0` ... `str[(strlen(str)) - i]` is the `'\0'` byte, so effectively you're making the second string be the empty string (even though there may be stuff after the terminating `'\0'`).

Comment: Your code reverses the second string, and there is also an one-off index error. Is this by purpose?

Comment: Your format specifier is wrong: `%[^\n]s` This is a mix of `%[]` and `%s`. That `[]` part is not a modifier for `%s` but an own format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

With your code, `second[0] == '\0'`. It corresponds to `str[strlen(str)]`. So the second string is seen as empty effectively.

There are two others issues:

- We did not close the first string with `'\0'`.
- For building the 2nd string, you are reading the input string from the end. I assume that it is not what you intend to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    // your code goes here
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        char str[1000];
        int i,j;
        while((getchar())!= '\n');
        scanf("%s",str);
        int len = strlen(str);
        int position = (len + 1) / 2; 
        char first[(len/2)+1], second[(len/2)+1];
        for (i = 0; i < (len/2); i++)
        {
            first[i] = str[i];
            second[i] = str[position + i];
        }
        first[len/2] = '\0';
        second[len/2] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n",first);
        printf("%s\n",second);
    }
    return 0;
}
```